# OleDB Data provider can not be found VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, oracle, vba, odbc, oledb

I am almost not familiar with VBA (have had some courses back at school and that's it). Now I need to connect to Oracle database (which is running on remote server) from Excel file. I've goggled around and found some examples. So, there is the following code I have written so far:

```
    Sub Try()
         Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
         Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
         Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
         Dim chunk() As Byte
         Dim fd As Integer
         Dim flen As Long
         Dim Main As ADODB.Parameter
         Dim object As ADODB.Parameter

     Stil = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton1
        Titel = "db connection test"
    '   Meldung anzeigen.
        Antwort = MsgBox("trying to connect to db", Stil, Titel, Hilfe, Ktxt)

         ' Connect to the database using ODBC [msdaora][ORAOLEDB.Oracle]Provider=ORAOLEDB.Oracle;
         With cn
             .ConnectionString = "Provider=ORAOLEDB.Oracle;Password=pass;User ID=usr;Data Source=host:port:sid"
             .Open
             .CursorLocation = adUseClient
         End With

         ret = cn.Execute("create table newtesttable (main integer, object oid)")

         ' Here is an example if you want to issue a direct
    ' command to the database
         '
         'Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
         'With cmd
         '    .CommandText = "delete from MYTABLE"
         '    .ActiveConnection = cn
         '    .Execute
         'End With
         'Set cmd = Nothing

         '
         ' Here is an example of how insert directly into the
     ' database without using
         ' a recordset and the AddNew method
         '
         Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
         cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
         ' cmd.CommandText = "insert into newtesttable(main,object) values(?,?)"
         cmd.CommandText = "select * from test"
         cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

         ' The main parameter
        ' Set main = cmd.CreateParameter("main", adInteger, adParamInput)
         'main.Value = 100 '' a random integer value ''
         'cmd.Parameters.Append main

         ' Open the file for reading
         'fd = FreeFile
         'Open "myBlobFile.txt" For Binary Access Read As fd
         'flen = LOF(fd)
         'If flen = 0 Then
          '   Close
           '  MsgBox "Error while opening the file"
            ' End
         'End If

         ' The object parameter
         '
         ' The fourth parameter indicates the memory to allocate
     ' to store the object
       '  Set object = cmd.CreateParameter("object", _
       '                                       adLongVarBinary, _
       '                                       adParamInput, _
                                              flen + 100)
       '  ReDim chunk(1 To flen)
       '  Get fd, , chunk()

         ' Insert the object into the parameter object
       '  object.AppendChunk chunk()
       '  cmd.Parameters.Append object

         ' Now execute the command
         Set rs = cmd.Execute

     '   Mldg = "test"
        Stil = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton1
        Titel = "asdasdasd"
    '   Meldung anzeigen.
        Antwort = MsgBox(rs, Stil, Titel, Hilfe, Ktxt)
         ' ... and close all
         cn.Close
         Close

 End Sub
```

I believe there are many problems in this code, but at the moment it fails when trying to execute .Open, saying, that  `"Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed"`. After that I've found that I need to download and install ORAOLEDB.dll. I did this by installing ORAOledb11.dll (I've tried both 32 bit and 64 bit, thou my machine is 64 bit). I've installed it by executing `regsvr32 OraOLEDB11.dll`.

Unfortunately the problem is till there. So, what could be the steps to troubleshoot this problem?
Can I somehow ensure, that Oraoledb is properly installed on my machine?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe that should help: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/excel-make-query-oracle In general, connecting Oracle to Excel is much more complicated than e.g. "native" MSSQL. Good luck!

Comment: 1 more link that helped me several months ago: http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/how-to-query-oracle-from-excel-2007/

Comment: Go into Regedit and see if the key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\OraOLEDB.Oracle exists. The OLEDB driver is not installed by default when you install an Oracle client (you have installed an Oracle Client haven't you?). Incidentally this syntax is also wrong the Data Source is the entry in the TNSNAMES file that refers to your database. But this will not give you the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I do have above mentioned key in the registry.

Answer (score 4):

**32-bit OS**

I managed to get this working on  **Windows XP**  virtual machine by downloading oracle OLEDB provider from Oracle official website **Oracle10g Provider for OLE DB Version 10.1.0.4.0**. 
Current working [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/utilsoft-088126.html)  OLEDB for older OS (32 - bit)

But be aware it will replace JDK and JRE to lower version (It can be prevented by playing with the configuration xml - **products.xml** - I did not have enough of mental health potion, so I did full install instead). Afterwards you need to delete reference in environment variables as it may effect other programs.
After installation, I registered OraOLEDBxx.dll with **regsvc32**

I was connecting to oracle db 11G with excel 2003. :)

**Connection string**

I had to enable extensions (ActiveX Data Object and record libraries). My function returning connection was:

```
Public Function connectToDb(provider As String, host As String, sid As String, user As String, pwd As String, db As String) As ADODB.Connection
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim dbConnectStr As String

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    If provider = "Oracle" Then
        dbConnectStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & host & ":1521/" & sid & ";User Id=" & user & ";Password=" & pwd & ";"
    Else

    End If
    conn.ConnectionString = dbConnectStr
    conn.Open
    Set connectToDb = conn
End Function
```

**64-bit OS but 32-bit Office**

When our VMs migrated to 64-bit **Windows 7** with **Excel 2010**. Make sure you will download **ODAC** - Oracle Data Access Components -  for right **-bit** version of your excel installation because I had 32-bit excel installed and thought it was 64-bit (as windows is 64-bit) so I was giving birth trying to get this working with **64-bit** ODAC version. Afterwards I did download **32-bit version** and it works just as before. For installation just follow install instructions included in downloaded archive folder.

Current working [links](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html) for ODAC on Oracle website

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately I can't test it anymore:) and thus accept as a correct answer, but upvoted anyway;)

Comment: @AlexK. i am okey with it.. i just wanted to share what were my almost-week-long struggles.. I have got the same error you have here, when was trying to use 64-bit DLLs with 32-bit excel..

Comment: That did the trick , and without data source : dbConnectStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & host & ":1521/" & sid & ";User Id=" & user & ";Password=" & pwd & ";" - Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can insure that your connection string is accurate by creating a text file with the ending *.udl* then close and open the file.  You'll be prompted with a user interface to connect to the server.  Enter your info and test the connection.  Then if your connection is working close the file.  Open that file in text format and copy the connection string into your code.  Also be sure that your reference library is selected for ADO.  This line looks wrong:

```
Data Source=host:port:sid
```

Below is a sample I use to pull in the sql from text and extract results to text.

```
 Public Function ObjectConnect(AID As String, APswd As String)

 ObjectConnect = "Provider=ORAOLEDB;Password=" & APswd & ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & AID & ";Data Source=(nameofserverConn)"

 End Function

Sub RunSQL()

Dim strConn As String
Dim Query As String
Dim txt As Object
Dim ns As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim txtfile As Object
Dim f As ADODB.Field
Dim myFileSystemObject As Object
Dim txtN As String
Dim DL As String


FName1 = ""
Query = ""
txtStrngX = ""

Set ns = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
ns.ConnectionTimeout = 99000
ns.CommandTimeout = 99000



ns.Open ObjectConnect('UserID', 'Password') 'this is a public function w. userform for people to enter ID and Password.
With rs
    .ActiveConnection = ns
      'however you're writing the sql it would go here.
    .Open Query 
End With


If rs.State <> 0 Then
    DL = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
    RecordsetToText rs:=rs, FullPath:=txtN, ValueDelimiter:=DL  'this is a sub function that writes to a text file.  Didn't include the code but left this.  Here you would want to do something with the recordset.
End If

On Error Resume Next
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing


End Sub
```