# Excel VBA Connection to Oracle

Tags: excel, oracle, vba, connection-string

I am trying to connect to Oracle XE 11.2 using VBA and Excel. Oracle is installed on the same machine as Excel. I have also installed the 32 bit client tools. I have tried various methods found online but none of them seem to work.

Per the suggestion on the post [OleDB Data provider can not be found VBA/Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836274/oledb-data-provider-can-not-be-found-vba-excel) I was able to create an ".udl" file that successfully connected. However when I used the connection string in my code I get the error "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed".

```
Sub test2()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionTimeout = 99000
cn.CommandTimeout = 99000
cn.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=Oracle!;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SYSTEM;Data Source=DESKTOP-NAME"
End Sub
```

I believe the problem is I don't have the right references selected but I have tried many combinations and can't find any that work. Any help would be appreciated. If I need a reference please list out the exact reference(s) names.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: It is "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects"

Comment: I have tried "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" and "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" separately. Neither fixed the problem.

Comment: Did you install an Oracle Client?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the 32 bit client.

Comment: Oracle Client including the "OLE DB Provider"?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by including the OLE DB Provider. I simply downloaded and installed the client.

Comment: It is one of the options you can select/unselect in the installer options. btw. in case you downloaded and installed only the "Instant Client" you have to install OLE DB provider from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html

Comment: I have tried installing the driver using the client and the install seems to get stuck. I have downloaded just the driver and tried to install it but get errors during install. Is there any way you could give me a call and walk me through this? I would really appreciate it. 812-661-1462

Comment: Try it in a chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111179/oracle-installation-issue

Comment: My reputation is not high enough to use chat.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work by uninstalling the 64 bit XE SERVER and then installing the 32 bit version. I then installed the administration software (32 bit).