# How to connect to oracle 9i database from excel?

Tags: excel, oracle

I am working on oracle database.
I am using toad for that.
DB is in remote location say in IP 198.0.0.0
with user name as 'aaa' pwd as 'xxx'

I want to connect my DB to excel.
So that I can run query and get the results directly in excel.
Can I do that in excel 2003.?
If I can do, how to do connection.

I tried with Data - > Import external data - >New database query

It is not working

Thanks for your help,
I did googling.I didn't get help

Comment: "It is not working"  And what does that mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an ODBC data source set up already and use that as your data source in Excel.  The ODBC connection in turn points to your database. Of course this all assumes a properly installed Oracle client which is sounds like you have if you are able to use Toad, login and issue queries and see results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836274/oledb-data-provider-can-not-be-found-vba-excel/33276044#33276044